# Measuring time for a selenium tests

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea, jmeter, measure

I have some problem concerning connection between Intellij IDEA and jMeter.
I have a lot of automatic tests and in some situations I'd like to measure test execution time, especially when we have old gui without ajax.

How can do it ? How can I connect jMeter to selenium in Intellij IDEA environment or maybe exists other way to measure a time for GUI.

Thank very much for any help.

Comment: you can add a timestamp between your test steps.

Comment: Is it possible to measure this time using jMeter ?

Comment: Jmeter has a webdriver plugin. Unsure how portable selenium scripts are to this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need JMeter for some reason in addition to measure timings? JMeter is more for performance testing. If all you need is a simple timing between events, you can use [`org.apache.commons.lang3.time.StopWatch`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang3/time/StopWatch.html).

A simple example would be

```
StopWatch stopwatch = new StopWatch();
stopwatch.start();
Thread.sleep(1000); // a valid use of Thread.sleep() ;)
stopwatch.stop();
System.out.println(stopwatch.toString());
```

Which outputs

```
00:00:00.999
```

Comment: Thank for answer. However if I want to measure time for some selenium test for 100 users simultaneously. How to run selenium test for 100 users ?

Comment: You don't. Selenium is meant to automate a user scenario on a website not load testing 100 users. You want something like JMeter, LoadRunner, etc. and it will provide a mechanism to do timings but it won't use Selenium.